# Django Save multiple selections for the same input name to the database and getting it back in another view

Tags: django

I need to save several checkboxes values that have the same name.
like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="eth_hisp" value="Mexican" id="eth1_hisp" class='chk-btn'/>
<label for='eth1_hisp'>Mexican</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="eth_hisp" value="Cuban" id="eth2_hisp" class='chk-btn'/>
<label for='eth2_hisp'>Cuban</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="eth_hisp" value="Puerto Rican" id="eth3_hisp" class='chk-btn'/>
<label for='eth3_hisp'>Puerto Rican</label>
```

I need to store values which will be selected (checked) to database as one value. (It is possible to be done as the string with the command:

```
eth_hisp=''.join(form.getlist('eth_hisp'))
```

Question: How to transfer these values back to the view (it will be another view as a variable name? In other words, There is another view where selected checkboxes has to be also selected if in the example above they were checked (1 view - is user view, 2 view is admin edit view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the simplest way not to change the whole project and to keep their (really not good) structure ))).

Skipping the model related part. 
in the view.

```
obj=<Model Name> #where eth_hisp is stored
data=[]
if 'Mexican' in obj.eth_hisp:
    data['mexican']=True
# And so for any similar value within the same name
```

data dict has to be transferred with render.

In the template where these values have to be prepoppulated (admin view);

```
<input type="checkbox" name="eth_hisp" value="Mexican" id="eth1_hisp" class='chk-btn' {% if mexican %} checked {% endif %}>
<label for='eth1_hisp'>Mexican</label>
```